# Fast way of splitting data table by value of an column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a big data table object like the following:

```
> head(trade_hist,12)
        timestamp   price takeFrom volume
 1: 1448905691000 2440.21      ask  0.346
 2: 1448905691000 2440.11      bid  0.016
 3: 1448905691000 2439.78      ask  0.019
 4: 1448905691000 2440.16      ask  0.470
 5: 1448905691000 2439.59      bid  0.029
 6: 1448905691000 2440.16      bid  0.006
 7: 1448905691000 2439.75      ask  0.045
 8: 1448905691000 2440.12      ask  0.042
 9: 1448905691000 2439.62      bid  0.168
10: 1448905692000 2439.49      ask  0.016
11: 1448905692000 2439.46      ask  0.013
12: 1448905692000 2439.43      bid  0.394
```

and I intend to split it into a list of data tables by timestamp. I can do:

```
> trade_hist_list <- split(trade_hist,f=trade_hist$timestamp)
> trade_hist_list[[1]]
       timestamp   price takeFrom volume
1: 1448905691000 2440.21      ask  0.346
2: 1448905691000 2440.11      bid  0.016
3: 1448905691000 2439.78      ask  0.019
4: 1448905691000 2440.16      ask  0.470
5: 1448905691000 2439.59      bid  0.029
6: 1448905691000 2440.16      bid  0.006
7: 1448905691000 2439.75      ask  0.045
8: 1448905691000 2440.12      ask  0.042
9: 1448905691000 2439.62      bid  0.168
```

However this process is really slow, since the timestamp is sorted it should be a lot faster. Any suggestions? thx!

Comment: your example is not reproducible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure about performance but you can try this one. Current proposal as `split.data.table` method. It may looks complex, it is just because it handles some nested sub-lists but that doesn't make any different on your case.

```
split.data.table <- function(x, f, drop = FALSE, by, flatten = FALSE, ...){
    if(missing(by) && !missing(f)) by = f
    stopifnot(!missing(by), is.character(by), is.logical(drop), is.logical(flatten), !".ll" %in% names(x), by %in% names(x))
    if(!flatten){
        .by = by[1L]
        tmp = x[, list(.ll=list(.SD)), by = .by, .SDcols = if(drop) setdiff(names(x), .by) else names(x)]
        setattr(ll <- tmp$.ll, "names", tmp[[.by]])
        if(length(by) > 1L) return(lapply(ll, split.data.table, drop = drop, by = by[-1L])) else return(ll)
    } else {
        tmp = x[, list(.ll=list(.SD)), by=by, .SDcols = if(drop) setdiff(names(x), by) else names(x)]
        setattr(ll <- tmp$.ll, 'names', tmp[, .(nm = paste(.SD, collapse = ".")), by = by, .SDcols = by]$nm)
        return(ll)
    }
}
```

if you will provide reproducible example I can provide the function call on that example.

OK, let me guess...

```
split.data.table(trade_hist, by="timestamp")
```

Also you may need to use `setNumericRounding(0)` if you are grouping on POSIXct, but I'm not really sure about that.

Comment: @Frank yes, there is a documentation draft in above url if anyone interested

Comment: @jangorecki could I call it with multiple by? Say, we have Year as well, so will it work with `split.data.table(trade_hist, by=c("Year", "timestamp"))`  ?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux yes, by default it will result nested lists, use `flatten=TRUE` to have concatenated for non-nested lists with `year.timestamp` as names of returned list.